# why is string considered as a singular data type in SV?

Tags: system-verilog

in the LRM of the SV it is mentioned that the string are singular data type, but why even though they can be indexed like array?

Comment: This question might fare better over at [COMPUTER **SCIENCE** @SE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Much more time is spent reading posts than typing them: Please spell out none-too-common acronyms like LRM and SV.

Comment: @greybeard This question was tagged [tag:system-verilog]. Anyone who knows what that tag means knows SV is short for **S**ystem**V**erilog and LRM is its **L**anguage **R**eference **M**anual.

Answer (score 1):

*Singular* is a concept from the Vera language, one of the predecessors of SystemVerilog, and many other features of SystemVerilog rely on a string being a singular type to function properly. For example, the `inside` operator only works singular types on the left-hand-side. Since a `string` is a singular type, you can use it there. Same for `mailbox` items.

Keeping strings as singular types is easy for the implementation since is just a simple pointer.